# Getting content using force.com sites in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest, force.com-sites, contentdocument

I have a requirement where i have to download archived content from external system. However, salesforce does not allow to get archived content from REST API.

The way i can download the archived content is using  servlet.shepherd url (/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/0691g00000abcde). For this, I have to be logged in the system and then only i can download which is not possible when trying to retrieve content from external application.

So, I thought of creating a site in salesforce that can be accessed by any guest user. A vf page is associated with the site called TestVFPage.

```
<apex:page action="{!haveContent}" controller="SQX_TEST_APX">
```

The controller method is

```
public class SQX_TEST_APX {
    public PageReference haveContent(){
return new PageReference('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/0691g000000ABCDEF');
}
}
```

Using above code, I can download the content in incognito mode in browser. However, I want to get the content as api call from external system. 
I get the following response using POSTMAN,

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">





    <script>
        function redirectOnLoad() {
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/0691g000000dXzNAAU'); }  else 
if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/0691g000000dXzNAAU');
} else {
window.location.href ='/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/0691g000000dXzNAAU';
} 
} 
redirectOnLoad();
    </script>

</head>


</html>
```

So, Is it possible to get archive content from external system as api calls (or sth similar).

I understand that unarchived content can be retrieved using REST calls. I want archived content and feed it to a system.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this video explaining how to "[Download Attachments & Files from Salesforce using NodeJs application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsbIAhhPOu4)"

The script uses `jsforce` to connect to salesforce and runs a query to download files.

Its about downloading attachments but you can adapt the query for `ContentDocument` with `isArchived = true` and other filters for your use case.